# Angular 7 on Chrome 41: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

Trying to get my angular 7 application to run on chromium v41 (WSR).
Everything works great on newer browsers, but chrome 41 is throwing me an exception: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"

```
...
onComplete: (self) => {},
...
```

My polyfills.ts:

```
/** IE9, IE10, IE11, and Chrome <55 requires all of the following polyfills.
 *  This also includes Android Emulators with older versions of Chrome and Google Search/Googlebot
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
...
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I missing something to get it to work on chromium 41?

Posted on issues as well:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30279

Comment: The compiler should be converting all the arrow functions to standard functions when targeting es5. Are you sure `onComplete: (self) => {},` is reachable for the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the root of this cause.

I've been using typed.js and imported the wrong file to be used.

Basically had

```
import Typed from 'typed.js/src/typed.js';
```

which was probably auto-imported.

Changed to

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';
```

and it started working again!